# IE9 CSS3 property applied but not supported

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, animation

For various reasons I want to check whether a browser supports CSS3 animations. I do not want to use modernizer for this.

What I did is the following:

```
var el = document.getElementById('test');
el.style.animation = 'example 5s';
el.innerHTML = el.style.animation;
console.log(el.style);
```

Made a div and an animation and applied that animation via js to the div. Then I went ahead an read the div's style to check if the animation property is empty (browser can not interpret the animation correctly) or not.

This works everywhere except IE9.

IE9 console.log shows me

> animation"example 5s"

and thus reports the style as successfully set even though it can not interpret it.

What is going on there? And how can I make sure IE9 behaves the expected way?

Please see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8dkevm0c/21/

Comment: You may not want to use Modernizr, but you have just found out why it exists. Some tests are are simple as your example, and Modernizr started out as a collection of those tests. But there are plenty of features that are much harder to test for, for various reasons including browser bugs. Modernizr has evolved into a toolkit that can check a lot of these conditions. You may not want to use Modernizr, but if you want an accurate test you will probably end up with code for your it that is basically identical to the code for this test in Modernizr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with unsupported properties, the browser simply adds a new child to the `style` object with that value. You can replace `animation` with anything, `nonexistentProperty` or whatever in the fiddle and then it will work the same in all browsers. So you can't test for proper support in that way.

The solution, which I shamefully stole from this page:
http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/check-if-a-css-property-is-supported/
is to use `if ('property' in document.body.style)` in your JavaScript.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('test');
if ('animation' in document.body.style) {
  el.style.animation = 'example 5s';
  el.innerHTML = el.style.animation;
  console.log(el.style);
}
else
  el.innerHTML = 'Sorry, no animation';
```

```css
@keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}

/* The element to apply the animation to */
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  tes
</div>
```

Disclaimer: I don't have IE9 here, so I can't 100% vouch for this method. It does work correctly in the latest browsers though.

Comment: i see. that would have been the next thing I would have tried. I'll give it a shot and see if it works out.